# Locating and opening programs based on a word in python

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have a script where a user will input a program to open, and that script will open the program. The way I've done it isn't very efficient and so I'm leading into problems.

If I input "Open chrome", the script starts a search for a file called chrome.exe on your computer and then launches it. This works for a few programs like chrome.exe, steam.exe etc, but there are programs where their exe file is named differently.

For example, "Open word". The script will search for a program named word.exe, but the Microsoft Word exe file is actually named WINWORD.EXE, so the search will fail.

So my question is how can I make this more efficient? I know I could add exceptions and find the directory of the file myself but this would be impractical to do for many programs.

```
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        success = False
        print (">")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("Processing...")
            t = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print (": " + t)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Unknown input") 
            continue
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("An error occured at GAPI\nA common cause is lack of internet connection")
            continue

        if "open" in t:
            t = t.replace("open","")
            t = t.replace(" ","")
            z = t
            speak = "Opening " + z
            t = t + ".exe"
            print (t)

            for a,d,f in os.walk("C:\\"):
                for files in f:
                    if files == t.lower() or files == t.capitalize() or files == t.upper():
                        s.Speak(speak)
                        pat = os.path.join(a,files)
                        print (pat)
                        sp.call([pat])
                        success = True
```

Edit:

I did some research and found out about something called filename pattern searching. I've been unable get it running, any ideas?

Comment: I can't think of a practical solutions because the number of exceptions and ambiguities will be infinite. For instance if you try to set up a regular expression to direct "word" to "winword" there can also be abi word or wordpad installed on the system. Besides, you should provide some code example to enable us to help you.

Comment: That's the code.